# Common tabs footer is placed under navbar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, tabs, angular-ui-bootstrap

In `angular-ui v0.3` I used old tabs directive with common footer like this example. http://plnkr.co/edit/5K1xIf

Now I want upgrade to `0.4`, but it has new version of tabs, where content transcludes into `navbar` and common footer becomes header.

How do I change my code so that tabs can work as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include the footer in each individual tab by using the `ng-include` directive:

```
<tabset>
   <tab heading="First Tab">
      First Tab content
      <div ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>         
   </tab>
   <tab heading="Second Tab">
      Second Tab content 
      <div ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>      
   </tab>       
</tabset>
```

And an example of the `footer.html`:

```
<div class="footer">tabs footer</div>
```

Comment: there is a good solution, but actually in my case footer has facebook like button, which must be unique element. Because I think about to move footer outside the tabs, and make continious border with CSS.